# Angularjs select validation not working

Tags: angularjs

I want to tell user to select any option from select other than first (index=0). I saw few examples and tried but not working for me:

```
<select ng-model="patient.gender" name="gender" class="form-control" required>
  <option>- Select -</option>
  <option value="Male">Male</option>
  <option value="Female">Female</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<div class="error" ng-show="Form.gender.$invalid">
    Select gender
</div>
```

What to change here?

Comment: try this `<option value="">- Select -</option>` add empty value to option which acts as option caption . req'd field validation should work now .

Comment: Thanks @supercool, value="" did the trick :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

provide empty(default value) to option, so required field validation will fire on selection.

**Html:**

```
<select ng-model="patient.gender" name="gender" class="form-control" required>
  <option value=''>- Select -</option> //Default value to empty
  <option value="Male">Male</option>
  <option value="Female">Female</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```